# C# WPF Library for a AutoSuggest TextBox

Tags: library, c#, wpf

I found some AutoComplete TextBoxes, which allow completing the input on-the-fly when typing in.

I am looking for the same, but it should be a TextBox that also allows different input which is not in the list provided with the TextBox, so I can easily add new entries by just typing them in - an AutoSuggest TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a Editable ComboBox in WPF. This will allow for you to have a list of items that you can select by the drop down or autofill when typing but gives you the benefit of free typing in a value also.

For Example:

> ```
> <ComboBox Name="comboExample" IsEditable="True">  
>   <ComboBoxItem Content="A"/>  
>   <ComboBoxItem Content="B"/>  
>   <ComboBoxItem Content="C"/>  
> </ComboBox>
> ```

If you just want to use the combobox as a textbox then just look at the text property of the combobox, in my example it would look like this in c#: 'comboExample.Text'. If you want to see if it used one of the predefined items, the comboExample.SelectedItem will have an item in it, otherwise if you free typed a new value that property will be null. I know this is not exactly what you asked for but I think it will work for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The Syncfusion [AutoComplete](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/auto-complete) allows for handling the “Enter” key press and adding the text entered in the control to the collection. Please refer to this [sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/138636/AutoCompleteSample1417025873.zip).

[image]

Comment: The WPF license costs 1000$. I am sure there is something free out there. And the example didn't compile at first try.

Comment: @juergen-d The [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) is free. You need to download and install Essential Studio first to get it to compile. Regards, Davis

Comment: @juergend: If you are exclusively looking for something free, please add the [tag:gratis] tag to your question.

Comment: This synfusion version is not working properly when there are 10000 records in combobox. Please suggest performance with syncfusion textbox.

Comment: @user1241838 We have modified the [sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/180195/ze/AutoCompleteSample1417025873795772890) and tested by loading 10000 items into the AutoComplete, but we were unable to reproduce the reported behavior in our side.  Could you please check the sample and confirm if you see issues.